# Linux UI frequently freezes for <1 second

Tags: linux, laptop, freeze, thinkpad, xubuntu

The Linux Desktop (Xubuntu 16.04) freezes frequently (multiple times a minute) for less than 1-2 seconds and then returns operating normally.

During the freeze only the mouse cursor is movable.

The error occurs with and without a connected ac adapter.

The Laptop is a Thinkpad E550 with an Intel i7-5500U, 16GB RAM and a Samsung SSD 850 EVO 120GB. The average Load is between 0.5 and 0.7.

According to `smartctl` the SSD has no errors and gets trimmed before each shutdown.

Even powering the the second graphic adapter off, using `vgaswitcheroo` does not help:

```
# sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch 
0:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:05:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

The power management is already set to performance in the ThinkPad BIOS.

After each micro freeze the following messages occur int the syslog:

```
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.686075] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:9c98 = 5323c42/0
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.686082] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.693583] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x00000000002E8000).
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.693688] radeon 0000:05:00.0: WB enabled
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.693690] radeon 0000:05:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800355ffc00
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.693692] radeon 0000:05:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800355ffc04
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.693693] radeon 0000:05:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800355ffc08
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.693694] radeon 0000:05:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800355ffc0c
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.693695] radeon 0000:05:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800355ffc10
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.695260] radeon 0000:05:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90002835a18
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.795722] radeon 0000:05:00.0: VCE init error (-110).
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.989381] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.989388] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.989392] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.989410] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 2 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2868.989417] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 4 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2869.165112] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 2 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2869.165118] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2869.165153] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2869.165183] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2869.165213] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2869.165241] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:54 localhost kernel: [ 2869.165269] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
Jan 18 09:37:55 localhost kernel: [ 2869.812290] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to power management.

setting power management performance does not necessarily limit CPU c-state and p-state. You may want to manual set these parameters in BIOS (max c-state to c1, and disable pstate).

In addition, there are new intel drivers which overrides these settings, which need to be disabled using kernel commandline like

intel_idle.max_cstate=0,
intel_pstate=disable, 
processor.max_cstate=0

But not sure if these are applicable for Ubuntu. please check.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=203123) suggests that the issue may come from Intel Graphics drivers. The issue may be solved (to a degree) by switching to UXA acceleration. This can be done by adding

```
Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
```

to the relevant `Device` section of `xorg.conf`